# Can you always bucket $N$ colored balls into $k$ bins such that no color dominates any bin?

Tags: combinatorics

Given $N$ balls, each with a single color [there are $C\ge2$ colors], and given $2\leq k \leq \frac{N}{2}$ buckets, what are some sufficient/necessary conditions to be able to bucket the balls into $k$ buckets, such that for all the buckets, no one color dominates the bucket. By dominate, I mean that if bucket $k$ gets assigned $N_k$ balls, then at most $\frac{1}{2}N_k$ of them are the same colors.

Comment: @JaapScherphuis I meant there is a fixed number of colors $C\geq 2$ and each ball has one of these colors $C$. Sorry English is not my first language.

Comment: One obvious necessary condition is that no colour occurs more than $N/2$ times.

Comment: The obvious guess is that no colour occuring more than $N/2$ times is also a sufficient condition. Can you prove or disprove that?

Comment: I think it probably is sufficient. I think you can always split the balls and buckets into two smaller problems such that each still satisfies the condition, until you get down to only cases with a single buckets with no dominating colour. This suggests it can be proved more formally with strong induction.

Comment: Are you allowed to put all the balls in one bucket?

Comment: Are the numbers $N_k$ specified in the problem?

Comment: @bof I assumed that no buckets can be left empty. Although this is not explicitly stated, the condition $k\le N/2$ seems to be intended to make sure that every bucket can get at least 2 balls (or can be considered a consequence of the fact that you can't just put one ball in there, plus the unstated non-empty restriction).

Answer (score 0):

I think a neccesariy and sufficient condition would be that for each color, there are $\leq \frac{N}{2}$ balls with this color. Note that if N is odd, this means that the maximal number of balls with a color $\leq \frac{N}{2} -1$ and that means that it must hold that $C \geq 3$

Explanation - In order to have at most $\frac{1}{2}N_k$ balls in bucket $k$, we need to have at least $\frac{1}{2}N_k$ balls of another color (or other colors) in the bucket. So for each ball of color C, there has to be at least one other ball of a different color in the bucket to "match" it. If there are more than $\frac{N}{2}$ balls of color C this won't be possible to do in all buckets. If there are $\leq \frac{N}{2}$ balls of color C, this will be possible.

Comment: If you have $\le\frac N2$ balls of each color, why don't you just put all the balls in the first bucket? I guess I don't understand the problem. Is there some condition about the capacities of the buckets that I missed?

Comment: You can indeed put all the balls in one bucket (as far as the description goes). The question was, under what conditions is it possible to distribute the balls such that no bucket has a majority of balls in one color.